# Making strings entered add into an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I want the user input to be a string added to my array list each time the user inputs a new string. I think I am on the right track but I'm not entirely sure because I can't output my array. Here is my code.

```
System.out.println("input your word list");

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String phrase;
//not sure if phrase =""; is necessary but eclipse suggested it at one point
phrase = ""; 
ArrayList<String[]> wordlist = new ArrayList<String[]>();   

for(int i=0; i<phrase.length();i++){
  phrase = scanner.nextLine();
  wordlist.add(new String[] {phrase});
}

System.out.println(phrase);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(wordlist));
```

Comment: I would think some more about the condition on your `for` loop. It currently says "loop once for each character in the string `phrase`". Is that what you expected? If not, what should it be? How would you then translate that into a loop condition?

Comment: oh whoops, I want it to just loop every time a string is entered, not every time a character is entered in the string. When it loops, I want the Arraylist wordlist to now hold another string

Comment: Ok, so we know that you've got the wrong condition. How could you translate your actual condition into code? Should the loop ever stop? Is there a special phrase users can enter to end the loop?

Comment: Well making it to where it only runs on the input is fine, I guess I could do a do loop? and then just make a while condition for the user to say done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would using `ArrayList<String>` instead of `ArrayList<String[]>` be a possible solution? In that case you could just do something like this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0; i<3; i++){       //not sure what you're doing with your loop
                               //so will just get 3 inputs
    wordList.add(scan.next());
}
```

Then to print them each out you would do:

```
for (int i=0; i<wordList.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(wordList.get(i));
}
```

OR if you prefer for-each:

```
for (String word : wordList){
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit :-  here you go this takes all input to array list until the user types quit and displays all the inputs:-

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     System.out.println("input your word list");

     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     ArrayList<String> wordlist = new ArrayList<String>();

     String input = "";
     while(!input.toLowerCase().equals("quit"))
     {
         input = scanner.nextLine();

         if(!input.toLowerCase().equals("quit"))
             wordlist.add(input);
     }

     for(int i = 0; i < wordlist.size(); i++)
     {
         System.out.println(wordlist.get(i));
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this still isn't doing , I want to print the entire array list just so that I can see that all of the strings entered are in the array list

Comment: I want the user to enter like "potato" and the array prints [potato]. and if he enters every single vegetable ever I want it to print [potato, carrot, etc, etc]

Comment: @Justin please check the edit, is that how you need?

Comment: Yes the problem was that i was using .length and not .size...Thank you very much for your time @NullSaint